# How can I pass parameters inside the 'then' function and 'catch' function of Laravel's Bus::batch?

Tags: laravel

While passing the ID to the `then` function, its value becomes `null`. However, I want to access the ID inside the `then` and `catch` functions to update the response value in the MongoDB. Is it possible to find the ID of the batch inside the `then` function when it's not being retrieved?

Here's the code snippet:

```php
$batch = Bus::batch($jobs)
            ->then(function (Batch $batch , $id) {
                $data = [
                    'batchResponse' => [
                        'status' => 'success',
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                        'data' => [
                            'message' => 'Queue processed successfully.',
                            'batch' => $batch,
                        ]
                    ],
                ];

                logging($data);
                loggingMongodb($data, $id);
            })->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e , $id) {
                $data = [
                    'batchResponse' => [
                        'status' => 'failure',
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                        'data' => [
                            'message' => 'Queue filed to process.',
                            'batch' => $batch,
                            'exception' => $e->getMessage(),
                        ]
                    ],
                ];

                logging($data);
                loggingMongodb($data, $id);
            })->name('Mail Batch Process')->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 3):

If id is not genereated inside Batch Jobs, you can use that id inside then method like below

```
 Bus::batch($jobs)
        ->then(function (Batch $batch) use ($varA, $varB) {
           // Here now you can reuse or access $varA and $varB
        })
        ->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e){
            //Report errors
        })
        ->name('name')
        ->onConnection('connection')
        ->onQueue('queue')
        ->dispatch();
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly pass a variable to the then and catch closures of a Laravel batch process since they are executed asynchronously when all the jobs finish. The batch object itself is available within these closures, but other variables from the outer scope are not directly accessible.

As an alternative solution, you can store the necessary ID in the batch name when dispatching the batch. Later, you can retrieve the ID from the batch name within the `then` and `catch` closures. This allows you to work with the closures asynchronously.